# Two .a files (one for device other for simulator)

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, ios, linker, .a

I was given an SDK which I need to integrate into an iPhone app. I was given 2 .a files, one for simulator and one for the device. Right now, I have to constantly swap these files depending on the testing destination (device or simulator). Is there a way I can make it so Xcode automatically configures the right .a file depending on where I want to test it? Thanks.

Oh btw, I am using Xcode 4. Thanks!

Comment: Removed Objective-C tag as this is not related to Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try and build a fat, i386/arm version of the library by using lipo.

You can use this command:

```
 lipo -create liblib-i386.a liblib-arm.a -output liblib-fat.a
```

The linker will be able to extract just the symbols it needs from it according to the platform.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lipo to create a "fat binary" that contains both architectures.

```
lipo -create binary1.a binary2.a -output fatbinary.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create two targets and use the appropriate lib file.

Comment: Yea, but sometimes you may want to avoid a fat binary.